# Possible reducer case after a map function.

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to see if array.reduce would be a better option in this case. 
I'd like to return the string result instead of having to set a variable in the forEach loop.

So what I'm doing is seeing if there are any matches inside a string matching my regex. Then getting the text inside that match and replacing it with a variable I pass to it. All works great but I'd like to clean it up if I can. findReplaceTemplateString is a separate function and I'm ok with that. Its the forEach feels like I could use a reducer instead to return the completed string. But I'm new to reducers and not sure if this is a good case for it. Anyone have any thoughts on this.

```
  const reg = /\{.+?\}/g;
  const matches = tpl.match(reg);

  let str = '';      
  matches.map(item => item.slice(1, -1)).forEach((placeHolder) => {
    str = findReplace(tpl, placeHolder, props[placeHolder] || '');
  });
```

Comment: As a rule, if you're using a `.forEach` or a `.map` solely for modifying a different variable as a side-effect, it's a good use-case for `.reduce`.

Comment: Ok so this would be a good case then. Any help on how I would do this. All i've seen is examples of using reduce by adding one value to another. Thats not going to work in my case ? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see the point of overcomplicating it. Simply use [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) with function as a second parameter. That will dynamically replace your pattern with valid parameters.

```js
const input = 'Hi there, {name}! What are you doing in {city}?';
const props = {name: 'Alex', city: 'St Petersburg'};

const output = input.replace(/\{.+?\}/g, (p) => {
  return props[p.slice(1, -1)] || p /* here you may use '' */;
});

console.log( output );
```

Comment: Or use string template literals: `const output = \`Hi there, ${props.name}! What are you doing in ${props.city}?\`;`

Comment: @HereticMonkey Ha, yeah! Indeed it is ES6, so that will work nicely.